# Equality of a supremum of two Expectation

Tags: probability-theory

I got stuck to prove an equality in a detailed way and I hope, someone could tell to me, how to fix it. Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space. Let $\mathcal{K}$ be the set of all probability measure $Q$, which are absolutely continuous with respect to $P$. We are given a r.v. $X$. Suppose there is a $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\ge N$ we have

$$\inf_{Q\in\mathcal{K}}Q(X\ge n)=0$$

I want to verify (in detailed way) the following equality:

$$\sup_{Q\in\mathcal{K}}E_Q[-(X\wedge n)]=\sup_{Q\in\mathcal{K}}E_Q[-(X\wedge N)]\ge -N$$

The inequality is clear, since $-(a\wedge b)=-a\vee -b\ge -b,-a.$

We can rewrite the equality as:

$$\inf_{Q\in\mathcal{K}}E_Q[X\wedge n]=\inf_{Q\in\mathcal{K}}E_Q[X\wedge N]$$

My idea was: $E_Q[X\wedge n]=E_Q[X\wedge n(\mathbf1_{X\ge n}+\mathbf1_{X< n})]=nQ(X\ge n)+E[(X\wedge n)\mathbf1_{X<n}]$. The inf over the first term is zero, but at the end I did not get the RHS. So how can I prove this in a detailed way? The equality is stated in this [paper](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=delbane%20general%20probability%20spaces%20risk%20measure&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDkQFjAB&url=http://www.math.ethz.ch/~delbaen/ftp/preprints/RiskMeasuresGeneralSpaces.pdf&ei=hmjWUfKmHISdO_fXgdgP&usg=AFQjCNEbnattPWLdnrMPgL8SzoQbMuCLoQ&bvm=bv.48705608,d.ZWU), see proof of Theorem 5.4 the direction $3)\Rightarrow 1)$.

Comment: have solved the problem? If so, I would appreciate if you could provide an answer.

Comment: No, sorry. I can't provide a solution so far

Answer (score 2):

The equality is not true. You just need to consider $\mathcal{K}=\{P,Q\}$ (or its convex hull, if you want to satisfy the assumptions in the paper), where $P$ and $Q$ are such that $X$ $=$ $N-1$ a.s. under $P$, but $E^Q[X]<(N-1)$ with $Q(X>N)>0$.

Then clearly $P(X \geq n)=0$ for any $n \geq N$, while \begin{align*}\inf_{\mathcal{K}} E[X \wedge (N+1)]=E^Q[X \wedge (N+1)]=&E^Q[X \wedge N + 1_{\{N<X\}}(X \wedge (N+1)-N)]\\>&E^Q[X \wedge N]=\inf_{\mathcal{K}} E[X \wedge N].\end{align*}

Comment: So you think there is a mistake in the paper? I can't hardly believe that :)

Comment: @john8 A small gap in the proof of one lemma of a mathematics paper is certainly not such a rare occurence...It is very likely that the statement of the theorem is still true but the proof needs to be slightly modified, or that even if the theorem as written is not exactly correct that does not impact the main point of the paper. However finding out which is true is a more time-consuming task than finding a simple counter-example, so I will not pursue it :)

Comment: @pgassiat Thanks for your answer. Why does such a pair of probability measures exists such that Q is absolutely 
continuous with respect to P? Since 
$X=N−1$ a.s. under 
$P$, we have 
$X=N−1$ a.s. under 
$Q$, hence 
$E_Q[X]<(N−1)$ is not possible!

Comment: @math you are of course right that $Q$ is not absolutely continous wrt $P$. But all that is needed is that $\mathcal{K}$ is dominated by a common probability measure, and when you have 2 measures it is easy since you can just take $(P+Q)/2$. Maybe the confusion comes from the fact that my $P$ is not to be thought as the dominating measure as in the OP, and I should have written instead $\mathcal{K}=\{Q_1,Q_2\}$.

Comment: by the way I realize now that in the OP $\mathcal{K}$ is the set of ALL absolutely continous proba measures, whereas in the paper it does not have to be (it is just some subset). In the case where you take all probability measures then it is easy to see that $\inf_Q E^Q[X] = x_0:=\inf\{x , P(X\leq x)>0\}$ (just take $dQ/dP=\frac{1_{\{X\leq x\}}}{P(X\leq x)}$), and in this case both equalities are true whenever $N>x_0$, but only the second one for $N=x_0$.